# Copy/paste value a range in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

In order to apply the clean function to the range A1:B50 in my excel sheet, I wrote the code below. However this code won't paste the values I copied. Any idea what's wrong with it ? Thanks!

```
Sub clean ()
Dim ws

Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
ws.Range("D1:D50") = "=CLEAN(RC[-3])"
ws.Range("E1:E50") = "=CLEAN(RC[-3])"
ws.Range("D1:E50").Copy
ws.Range("A1:B50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ws.Range("D:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End sub
```

Comment: need to use the formula method of the range: `ws.range("").formula = "=CLEAN(...)"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the range "D1:E50" still wont paste in A1.

Comment: Try ws.Range("D1:D50").FormulaR1C1 = "=CLEAN(RC[-3])"

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` at the top. Use `Dim ws As Worksheet`. You forgot e.g. `Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook` before using `wb`. Also, you have to have values in the range `A1:B50`. You can simplify with `ws.Range("D1:E50") = "=CLEAN(RC[-3])"`. 'Copying by assignment' is much faster: `ws.Range("A1:B50").Value = ws.Range("D1:E50").Value` instead of the `...Copy` and `...PasteSpecial...` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Clean a Range

**Microsoft Links**

- [`CLEAN function`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clean-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41) (additional nonprinting characters)
- [`Top ten ways to clean your data`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/top-ten-ways-to-clean-your-data-2844b620-677c-47a7-ac3e-c2e157d1db19)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub cleanRange()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containinig this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1:B50")
    rg.Value = Application.Clean(rg.Value)
    
    ' These will not work:
    'rg.Value = WorksheetFunction.Clean(rg.Value)
    'rg.Value = WorksheetFunction.Clean(rg)

End Sub

Sub cleanRangeYourIdea()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containinig this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    ws.Range("D1:E50").Value = "=CLEAN(RC[-3])"
    ws.Range("A1:B50").Value = ws.Range("D1:E50").Value
    ws.Range("D:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Recreating a test case for your SUB, the minimun changes for your code to work are include in this snippet:

```
Sub clean()
Dim ws

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
ws.Range("D1:D2") = "=CLEAN(RC[-3])"
ws.Range("E1:E2") = "=CLEAN(RC[-3])"
ws.Range("D1:E2").Copy
ws.Range("A1:B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ws.Range("D:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Nonetheless, considering that VBA is very permissive (specially without Option Explicit) and for following good code practice), here I put some more fixes:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Clean1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    ws.Range("D1:D2").Formula = "=CLEAN(RC[-3])"
    ws.Range("E1:E2").Formula = "=CLEAN(RC[-3])"
    ws.Range("D1:E2").Copy
    ws.Range("A1:B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ws.Range("D:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Both codes were tested and they work. Until this time, I did not touched the logic which could be optmized with vba functions but does not seem to bad to rely on excel functions

Sorry for the format of the post, I'm new here.

Edit: I deleted a bold markdown to a word.